# Does regularly spaced via stitching contribute to standing waves on an RF PCB?

Tags: rf, pcb-design, grounding, via

Should vias be irregularly spaced? Can consistent spacing between ground vias create standing waves.

Has anyone ever heard of this? I've been doing this for awhile and I've never heard this and google wasn't returning anything remotely useful.

I've worked with a half-dozen or so RF specific engineers over the years and no one has ever brought this to my attention.

If you have heard of this, can you quote sources?

Edit: this is for 2.4GHz ISM bands like BTLE and Zigbee

Comment: What's the ratio of the via spacing to the RF wavelength?

Comment: as explained in the DELETED ANSWER, at high enough frequencies the skin effect and surface roughness cause the foils to become serious dampeners of any stored energy, which prevents the buildup of standing waves. The answer thus is: it depends on the frequency, the internal DAMPENING and the via spacing and losses inside the vias. Should randomness help? Sure, at lower frequencies where dampening is inadequate. But there are many params involved.

Comment: I added an edit for the frequency band.